How does VPA addresses in UPI deep links decides whether it will be blocked by all apps or will allow payment?
I have created and tested with several UPI deeplinks, all are able to open the respective apps (Google Pay, paytm, phonepe) with all the information including amount prefilled but only few allows payment to go through and the rest gets blocked and gives limit error even though no limit has reached.
There are some cases in which payment goes through for gpay and phonepe but paytm blocks the payment.
So overall 3 types of VPA's I have found

All payment apps allows payment through deep link of this VPA, example: upi://pay?pa=reddyreddyflyashbricks@sbi&pn=pay&am=1.00&tn=88jj&cu=INR
GPAY and Phonepe allows, Paytm blocks, example: upi://pay?pa=8815686922.41573056@sbi&pn=pay&am=1.00&tn=88jj&cu=INR
All apps blocks, example: upi://pay?pa=yespay.smesm000016887@yesbankltd&pn=pay&am=1.00&tn=88jj&cu=INR

According to NPCI documentation https://drive.google.com/file/d/15h_Mom1Y7abJJIibUuC2Qjl1gh5LE97U/view
the deeplink should require signature but how to get this signature as no app or banks are providing keys to sign.
Further, above mentioned deep links work even without a signing key so how are they working?
I have created a page for examples of both types of vpa deep links (without signing key) mentioned https://chocolate-ariela-3.tiiny.site/ for testing with all apps links to test above behaviour. (Required deep links VPA are of third party found in a web app where it is working)
All VPA's tested by me are merchant VPA's from different banks and all gets blocked even tried with sbi ones like the third party ones that are working.
So how is it getting decided which one to block?
